# LuaLaTex with \pdfinterwordspaceon

Tags: pdftex, luatex, tagged-pdf

I am using LuaLaTex (only) with TexLive 2016 on Linux. Only utf-8 with Open Type fonts. No problem, works great. However, I am not much of a coder: "Monkey see, monkey do," with my altar to the Cargo Cult.

I see that from TexLive 2014, pdfTeX has a command `\pdfinterwordspaceon` that will insert spaces into the PDF text, for the purpose of reflow and accessibility. This was learned by browsing through other posts here at TeX Stack Exchange, so I am already aware of the things easily found by search.

But the command `\pdfinterwordspaceon` is not recognized when I put it in a preamble. Again, LuaLaTeX only. So, here is my question: Is there an alternative command that does the same thing, and is specific to LuaLaTeX? Or is it specific to pdfLaTeX and I am out of luck?

I can live with "out of luck" if necessary.

Comment: I don't think LuaTeX has support for `\pdfinterwordspaceon`.

Comment: You're out of luck.

Comment: I am not sure but maybe loading \RequirePackage{luatex85} before the \documemtclass command might help.

Comment: @HerbSchulz No, this is an experimental feature of pdfTeX introduced since the split off of LuaTeX. My guess is Hans will say you can do the same thing in Lua with appropriate callbacks, but that's non-trivial!

Comment: Guess I am out of luck. I am using luatex85 there (for other reasons). Consider my question as answered. I can always post-process with Acrobat Pro. In the past, using pdfTeX instead, I found that if I inserted the space character using textspace command (just once, but for each used font and all its variants) then the process of having Acrobat Pro add tags went much better. Apparently it makes better guesses for where to insert spaces, if it knows the width of the space character for each font, as a starting point.

Comment: @JosephWright It is 2018. Has `LuaTeX` gained this feature? Is it possible to do this using some `directlua` magic? or has an equivalent command been developed?